# Optimization Level in Rhino

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I am using Rhino 1.7R4 for my project.
By setting the optimization level of Rhino from 0 to -1(as i don't need extra class files to be generated) , i am getting unexpected results.

In Rhino code, under Codegen class which does some extra processing depending on optimization level set.

```
if (optLevel > 0) {
       /*
        * Collect all of the contained functions into a hashtable
        * so that the call optimizer can access the class name & parameter
        * count for any call it encounters
        */
        if (tree.getType() == Token.SCRIPT) {
            int functionCount = tree.getFunctionCount();
            for (int i = 0; i != functionCount; ++i) {
                OptFunctionNode ofn = OptFunctionNode.get(tree, i);
                if (ofn.fnode.getFunctionType()
                    == FunctionNode.FUNCTION_STATEMENT)
                {
                    String name = ofn.fnode.getName();
                    if (name.length() != 0) {
                        if (possibleDirectCalls == null) {
                            possibleDirectCalls = new HashMap<String,OptFunctionNode>();
                        }
                        possibleDirectCalls.put(name, ofn);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the only extra code that i could find in Rhino which would some extra bytecode optimization if opt level > 0.
But i am changing the optimization level in my use case from 0 to -1 in order to use the Rhino's Interpreter mode

So my question would be, what changes does rhino do the byte code when optimization level is changed from 0 to -1?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doc is still up to date on what the various optimization levels do in Rhino:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/Optimization

In practice, when you set the optimization level to -1, then you switch Rhino into interpreted mode, which means that it goes down a different path for executing the code than it does in compiled mode. Interpreted mode is, of course, much slower than compiled mode. We have a decent test suite in Rhino and don't regularly see differences between the two but there may of course be bugs that we need to fix.

What do you mean when you say, "i don't need extra class files to be generated"? When you run Rhino in the non-interpreted mode, it does indeed generate bytecode and then execute it, but it does not generate or save "class files" unless you do that explicitly -- but it runs faster.

Finally, 1.7R4 is a few releases old and many many bugs have been fixed. I'd encourage you to try a more recent release:

https://github.com/mozilla/rhino

Comment: Hi Greg,  thanks for your prompt reply. I am using java's viualvm tool to see class loading to fix one performance issue in my product. There when i pass 0/1 as optimisation level (i think at backend classes are getting created during generation of byte code during compilation of scripts) several classes are getting created again and again and are getting garbage collected.But when setting the optimisation level to -1,i don't see any extra class loading happening in PermGen space.So with optimization level set to -1,i see different o/p of compiled scripts as compared to optimization level of 0

Comment: Is there any way that you can actually compile the scripts and then cache them (Trireme does this, for instance)? Then you will save both time and memory.

Comment: I did that caching implementation in project to improve performance.
But changing the optimization level from 0 to -1 or to +1 gives different results from the scripts. So this shouldn't be the case, am i correct?
I mean the results should be same irrespective of the optimization level.

Comment: Your scripts should run the same regardless of optimization level. If you have any kind of reproducer and you can email it to the mozilla-rhino forum on Google Groups (you'll also find the link on GitHub) then there are various people there who can try.

Comment: I tired posting a questing on Rhino's google group but no response

Comment: How do i log a bug on Rhino?